# Creating a pen/eraser drawing app with background. Eraser erases background image, it should only erase pen

Tags: android, canvas, erase

I followed the fingerpaint code and some other code to create an app that allows you to draw onto the screen, with a background image in place to draw over top of.  In addition, I'd like to make an eraser tool that erases just the pen, not the background image.  I think I have to use two canvases for this, but couldn't figure out how it would work with Canvas' onDraw.

Here's my code.  Right now pen drawing works, and eraser drawing erases but it erases the background image.  I only want it to erase the pen.

If you could give me hints on what to do I would really appreciate it.

===

```
//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public MyView myView;
boolean penOn;
boolean eraserOn;
Bitmap bMap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Canvas myForegroundCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint;
private ArrayList<DrawAction> paths = new ArrayList<DrawAction>();
private ArrayList<DrawAction> undonePaths = new ArrayList<DrawAction>();
int selectedColor=Color.RED;
RelativeLayout container;
private int width;
private int height;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    View mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
            null);

    myView = new MyView(this);
    container = (RelativeLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.addView(myView);

    setContentView(mainView);


    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(16);

    Button pen = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.buttonpen);
    pen.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button eraser = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.buttonerase);
    eraser.setOnClickListener(this);
    pen.bringToFront();
    eraser.bringToFront();

}




public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        MainActivity.this.width = size.x;
        MainActivity.this.height = size.y;

        bMap = getBitmapFromAsset(MainActivity.this, "google.png");
        Bitmap background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap,
                MainActivity.this.width, MainActivity.this.height, false);

        mBitmap = background.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);


        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        myForegroundCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(40);
        final Iterator<DrawAction> i = paths.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {

            final DrawAction d = i.next();
            if (d.type.equals("pen")) {
                mPaint.setColor(d.color);
                mPaint.setXfermode(null);// clear the draw
                canvas.drawPath(d.path, mPaint);
                // myForegroundCanvas.drawPath(d.path, mPaint);

            } else if (d.type.equals("eraser")) {
                // mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);//transperent color
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));// clear the draw
                canvas.drawPath(d.path, mPaint);
                // myForegroundCanvas.drawPath(d.path, mPaint);

            }


        }



        mPaint.setColor(selectedColor);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // canvas.drawCanvas(myForegroundCanvas, 0, 0, null);

    }


    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {

        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        DrawAction d = new DrawAction(mPath, Color.RED);
        paths.add(d);

        mPath = new Path();
    }

    private void touch_start_eraser(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        selectedColor=Color.WHITE;
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move_eraser(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up_eraser() {

        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        DrawAction d = new DrawAction(mPath, true);
        paths.add(d);

        mPath = new Path();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

         if ( !penOn && eraserOn) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start_eraser(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move_eraser(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up_eraser();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}


public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String strName) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

    InputStream istr;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return bitmap;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonpen:
        penOn=true;
        eraserOn=false;
        break;
    case R.id.buttonerase:
        penOn=false;
        eraserOn=true;
        break;

    }

}
    }
```

===

```
//DrawAction.java, a helper class for holding the path and what type of drawing to do (pen or erase)
public class DrawAction {
public String type;

public Path path;
public int color;

public DrawAction(final Path p, final int color) {
    this.type="pen";
    this.path=p;
    this.color=color;
}
public DrawAction(final Path p, final boolean isEraser) {
    this.type="eraser";
    this.path=p;
}
     }
```

====

```
//activity_main.xml the layout code
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.doodle5.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonpen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Pen" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonerase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Erase" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and you want us to write the code for it?

Comment: I edited my question. If you could give me hints on what to do I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I ended up placing the background image as a background drawable on the container, and not drawing it onto the canvas.

In onDraw I commented out this line:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
```

In onCreate I added:

```
BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(backgroundBitmap);
container.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
```